# String values in java are not read properly

Tags: java, encoding, character-encoding

Actually I am receiving a JSONArray and I loop over every JSONObject. However, some json fields contain special characters. Forxample: ä, ö, Ä and etc.  A sample jsonobject is shown below:

```
{
    "field1": null,
    "field2": "Äpple",
    "field3": 1,
    "field4": null
}
```

field2 is being displayed as Ã\u201epple.
Is this some encoding issue? How can I fix this issue?
I am using the following piece of code to read the JSON objects in the array.

> Object dataObject = res.getJSONObject(i).get(column);
>   tempObject.put(column, dataObject);

Now the ***tempObject*** contains the column 'field2' with the distorted value.

Comment: What is the source of that JSON ? Is it correctly formatted before your parse it (readed as a `JSONObject` instance) ? Yes you have a problem of encoding, but hard to give a correct solution without knowing the source.

Comment: You need UTF-8 encoding

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to set response encoding to utf-8?

```
res.setContentType("application/json;charset=UTF-8");
```

Answer (score -1):

If sample is given as array then to read that array , you can convert JSON array into JsonObject and then fetch field1,field2 values as string.
e.g
jarr.get(i).getAsJsonObject().get("field1").getAsString();